# Serious consistency issues with Ubuntu 16.04 suspend - Nvidia Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend, systemd

Here are my system specs, I have a feeling this is specific to either System76 or Nvidia GTX 970M:

- System76 - Serval WS (serw8)
- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (64-bit)
- 6 GB GeForce GTX 970M – 1280 CUDA Cores
- 3.6 GHz i7-4790 (8MB Cache – 4 Cores – 8 Threads)
- 16 GB HyperX Dual Channel DDR3 at 1866MHz (2× 8GB)
- PCIe (M.2), SSD, HDD

I have inconsistent suspend issues, where, when waking from suspend, it *sometimes* but *frequently* wakes up to a black screen.

This has happened with both systemd suspend and `pm-suspend` suspend.

Pressing the power button, pressing the sleep button, trying any key combination, and closing and reopening the lid do nothing when at the black screen. The only thing I can do is either hard-shutdown or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) to perform a hard reset.

I have tried some different Nvidia drivers, but nothing has helped. I attempted using the open source nouveau drivers, but they didn't have good resolution and were *very* bad.

This is my current driver version (provided through the `system76-driver-nvidia` package): `367.27 from nvidia-367 (open source)`

I have asked System76 about this, and sadly, they are stumped. They believe it has something to do with systemd, but I'm not sure, and they aren't either.

I've checked `/var/log/pm-suspend` after a crash and it's empty. This is what shows up when it works correctly:

```
Initial commandline parameters: 
Tue Aug 23 12:29:55 CDT 2016: Running hooks for suspend.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend:
Linux Serval-WS 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Module                  Size  Used by
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
ctr                    16384  2
ccm                    20480  2
nvram                  16384  0
msr                    16384  0
vmnet                  53248  9
vmw_vsock_vmci_transport    28672  0
vsock                  36864  1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
vmw_vmci               65536  1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
vmmon                  86016  0
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               454656  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
bluetooth             520192  5 btbcm,btrtl,btusb,btintel
binfmt_misc            20480  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
mxm_wmi                16384  0
arc4                   16384  2
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
kvm                   540672  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  4
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
iwlmvm                311296  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
mac80211              737280  1 iwlmvm
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
nvidia_uvm            630784  0
mei_me                 36864  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
lpc_ich                24576  0
shpchp                 36864  0
wmi                    20480  1 mxm_wmi
tpm_crb                16384  0
acpi_pad               20480  0
mac_hid                16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
btrfs                 987136  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              102400  1 btrfs
hid_logitech_hidpp     20480  0
hid_logitech_dj        20480  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  4 usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
nvidia_drm             45056  1
nvidia_modeset        765952  6 nvidia_drm
drm_kms_helper        147456  1 nvidia_drm
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  81920  0
drm                   364544  4 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
mii                    16384  1 r8169
psmouse               126976  0
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                32768  1 ahci
nvidia              11075584  94 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm
sdhci_pci              28672  0
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_pci
video                  40960  0
fjes                   28672  0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       16388560     2477524    12216160       40292     1694876    13504604
Swap:      16783356           0    16783356
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/40inputattach suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/40inputattach suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/49tlp suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/49tlp suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend:
Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0'
OK
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
nVidia binary video drive detected, not using quirks.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/compiz-fix.sh suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/compiz-fix.sh suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend: success.

Tue Aug 23 12:29:56 CDT 2016: performing suspend
```

So this is a really tough problem, I'm willing to try anything (within reason), so let me know if you have any ideas. I'd really like to solve this problem because I use my lappy in college and it is very disappointing and dangerous to have to hard-reset randomly when waking from suspend, like a dice roll.

Comment: Check by issuing `echo mem > /sys/power/state`. If the problem persists, then it has nothing to do with systemd or any other userspace component (i. e. it is at the kernel side).

Comment: If you have solved this problem 2 years ago can you post an answer and accept it? If the problem has gone away can you delete this question? Thanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix No, this problem was never really solved, and I'm unable to accurately test the problem. However, this, the comments on this and the answer below may be useful to others even though there isn't an accepted answer. Necroing almost 3 year old questions isn't really productive.